# Search two different columns and then copy value if match

Tags: google-sheets

I have two different sheets. Both of them have column A which is date.

Its sports related so sheet 1 has the team with stats and sheet 2 has the schedule.

Sheet1 includes the "team" and sheet2 includes "home" in column B and "visitor" in column C.

What i want to do is that if the dates match to look at columns "home" and "visitor" and if let's say "home"="team" then copy the "visitor" value.

So basically to find each teams opponent on each date.

Hope that's clear enough

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pG7GH5mX_bb5VknqT579Vzo0Cs1NvNpBF45kAkFChY/edit#gid=0

here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&C2:C, {Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!D:D, Sheet2!C:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2:A&C2:C), 
 {TRIM(Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!D:D), Sheet2!C:C; 
  TRIM(Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!C:C), Sheet2!D:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but not all the values are showing up. However they should be as they are there. any ideas?